# Laravel - Check if user has submitted any records

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm doing a simple testing website, based on deviantart. On the index page, i want to display random graphics from random users. I've done that successfully but the problem is the fact that a user can have zero graphics, and i want to filter through and choose another user in that case.

So I've setup my models so that Graphics belongsTo User and a User hasMany Graphics

Here's the controller

```
    public function index()
{
    //Select three random users
    $user = \App\User::orderByRaw("RAND()")->take(3)->get();

    //Select a graphic from a user
    foreach ($user as $user) {
        $graphics[] = $user->graphics->first();
    }

    return view("page.index",compact('graphics'));
}
```

I just want to check if a selected random user has submitted any graphics and if not, select another random user, and I'm completely stumped as to how to do that?

Comment: is the graphics submitted through input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**
This is eloquent way if you want to try using DB then change accordingly.
`if(Graphics::where('user_id', '=', $randomUserId)->exists()){
   // user found
}`

Comment: Thank you, I've written this function that uses what you gave me, and I've also solved the problem taking a more different approach.                                                             public function generate_graphics($no_users)
 {
  $rnum_selected = [];
  $i = 1;
  while ($i <= 3) {
   $rnum = rand(1, $no_users);
   if (!in_array($rnum, $rnum_selected)) {
    $rnum_selected[] = $rnum;
    $graphic = \App\Graphic::where('user_id', '=', $rnum);
    if($graphic->exists()){
     $graphics[] = $graphic->get()->first();
     $i++;
    }
   }

  }
  return $graphics; 
 }

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've solved it

```
/** Generate graphics function
* Generates random users and fetches their graphics.
* $no_users is the last id of users or the max number of users.
* @return graphics collection
*/

public function generate_graphics($no_users)
{
    $rnum_selected = [];
    $i = 1;

    while ($i <= 3) {
        $rnum = rand(1, $no_users);
        if (!in_array($rnum, $rnum_selected)) {
            $rnum_selected[] = $rnum;
            $user = \App\User::find($rnum); 

            if($user != null){
                if(!$user->graphics->isEmpty()){
                    $graphics[] = $user->graphics->first();
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    return $graphics;
}
```

Comment: Instaed of using loop can you not use laravel join?